# Auth registration headache

Tags: python, django, redirect, authentication

I cannot work out why authenticate is not working in this registration view. I say that because the user is being entered into the database and it is redirecting to the next desired page (which has a login_required decorator), but then it redirects back to the login page. Authenticate is returning the new user in the shell with the values given. I have also debugged and pasted here: http://dpaste.org/J1HZ5/ What's going wrong?

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username = request.POST['username'],
                                    password = request.POST['password1'])

            login(request, new_user)
            context = RequestContext(request)    
            context['user_id'] = new_user.id
            context['new_user'] = new_user
            url = '/user/%s/' % new_user.id
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response("registration/register.html", {'form': form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'crewcal.views.index', name='home'),
    # url(r'^ssc/', include('ssc.foo.urls')),

    url(r'^events/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', 'crewcal.views.event'),
    url(r'^events/new/$', 'crewcal.views.new_event', name='new_event'),
    url(r'^commit/$', 'crewcal.views.commit'),
    url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', user, name='user'),
    url(r'^users/$', 'crewcal.views.users'),

    url(r'^register/$', register, name='join'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^log_in/$', log_in, name='log_in'),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Update the question with your `urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the django session middleware?

Comment: Session middleware is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to post your UserCreationForm code, but one thing I notice is that you're running the `authenticate(...)` call, but not actually checking the result of it and then redirecting. Looking at the Django source, there's a built in authentication form (`django.contrib.forms.AuthenticationForm`) and it verifies that the result if the `authenticate()` call is not none, and that the user is active and, if not, raises a form error.

Comment: That's true. But why should I do that? If the user creation form is validating correctly, the user information to be authenticated should be fresh and pure and should surely not fail. In any case, I know that it has been right (from database and shell tests) and yet authenticate() is not having it. Ps. UserCreationForm is the default one: `from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm`. Thanks for your attention though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', user, name='user'),
```

Make sure `user` is a valid view.

Comment: It is a valid view. It works when I call it independently of register. My problem is that (having debugged this), once a registration is made, it redirects to a user page, but then the @login_required decorator redirects again to the login. If I remove the login_decorator, the post registration redirect leaves me on the user page, which must mean that the login is not occurring correctly on register.

Answer (score 0):

Is your password field named `password1` or `password`?

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username = request.POST['username'],
                                    password = request.POST['password1']) # here?

            login(request, new_user)
            # rest of the code...
```